# TFS Custom Build Template - Get the team project collection without the Uri

Tags: c#, tfs

Is there anyway to get the collection URI from `IBuildDefinition` or other related 'services'.

I am trying to avoid having to supply the URI to the collection in the build template as a custom parameter. I am looking for a way to retrieve it programmatically from (in this instance) within `UITypeEditor` custom class.

Is there a way to query for this without resorting to hardcoding? It seems to me the build process itself (definition, controllers, agents, etc) knows which collection they are dealing with but how can I find out?

UPDATE: Here is sample code when you are inheriting from `UITypeEditor`. Then you just access the `TeamProjectCollection` property of the `VersionControlService`:

```
public class Editor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override object EditValue(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {           
        if (provider != null)
        {
            IWindowsFormsEditorService service = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

            if (service != null)
            {                       
                VersionControlServer vcs = provider.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;

                // Do what you need to do with it here
            }               
        }

        return value;
    }

    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of the override for UITypeEditor.EditValue the relevant line of code to obtain the TeamProjectCollection is

```
VersionControlServer vcs = provider.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;
```

And then it is in the property

```
vcs.TeamProjectCollection
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. It seems that this doesn't work if you reference the TFS 2010 assemblies and edit the build definition in VS 2012 (we use a TFS 2010 server). In VS 2010 it works like a charm.

Comment: I'm using TFS 2010 as well but haven't moved to VS2012 yet. I'll keep this in mind when we do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the TfsTeamProjectProjection object from IBuildServer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuildserver.teamprojectcollection.aspx

Then get you Uri from this object.

Comment: Let me try it out! I think this might be what I am looking for!

Comment: Is there a special way to retrieve the instance? I'm using: IBuildServer buildServer = (IBuildServer)provider.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer)); It is coming back null though.

Comment: I added an edit to my question so you can see what I ended up doing. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If you have the IBuildDefinition object, IBuildServer is actually a property, so you can just get it from there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddefinition.buildserver.aspx